# Bixby - getting user input for "yes/no" with navigation-mode in result-view

Tags: bixby

I have a result-view that reads and displays one item at a time:

```
if (size(this) > 1) {
      list-of (this) {
        has-details (false)
        where-each (item) {
          compound-card {
            content {
              image-card {
                aspect-ratio (4:3)
                title-area {
                  halign (Start)
                  slot1 {
                    text {
                      value ("#{value(item.title)}")
                      style (Title_M)
                    }
                  }
                }
                image-url ("#{value(item.thumbnail)}")
              }

              paragraph ("#{value(item.partialContent)}")
            }
          }
        }

        navigation-mode {
          read-one-and-next {
            page-content (item) {
              underflow-statement ()
              next-item-question ()
              overflow-statement ()
              overflow-question ()
              page-marker {
                if (isFirstNavPage(item)) {
                  choose (Random) {
                    template ("#{value(item.title)}. #{value(item.content)}. Do you want to hear more?")
                  }
                }
                else-if (isLastNavPage(item)) {
                  if (size(item) == 1) {
                    template ("#{value(item.title)}. You have reach the end of today's #{value(item.topic)}")
                  }
                }
                else {
                  choose (Random) {
                    template ("#{value(item.title)}. #{value(item.content)}. Do you want to hear more?")

                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

The question I have is: 
how do I get user voice input for "yes/no"?

the flow should be: 
- if user said "yes" - reads the next item in the navigation-mode. 
- if user said "no" - ends the navigation-mode.

I read something on using

```
followup
```

key for getting user yes/no input. But I struggle to find its use here. Should it be use alongside a converation-driver?

Answer (score 0):

The `next-page-question` key serves as a the prompt for asking the user if they want the next item in the list. The user's "yes" or "no" response is handled by navigation mode without any additional coding from you.

Comment: the thing is the "next-item-question" does not prompt for user input which is what im stuck at.

Comment: also next-item-question for read-many-and-next is deprecated but still a "required" field.. confusing documentation? 

https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/result-view.render.list-of.navigation-mode.read-one-and-next